# When the app is set for iOS5, will iOS4 users see it in the store?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

If I have an iOS5-only app, what will people with a previous version of iOS see in the store?

They see the app, but can't install it? They are asked to install iOS5 first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't let them install it. In iTunes it shows the version in there, and that data must be metadata that prevents the wrong version user from installing it. It gives them incompatible versions error to some extent. "This app is incompatible with" then the type of device.